# Convert List<int[]> of arrays to 2D - Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am trying to convert A `List<>` of `int` arrays to a 2D array.

The shape of `List<int[]>` is `List[Array1{x1,y1}, Array2{x2,y2}, ..., Array2{xn,yn}]`.

I want to convert it to a 2D Array, of type `int[][]`

I found the syntax for it to be: (Assume name of list to be **ans**)

```
ans.toArray(new int[0][]);
```

My question is why are we using `new int[0][]`. Why have the no. of rows been declared as **0**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`List.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--), with no arguments, returns a `Object[]`, not a `T[]`.

> ```
> Object[] toArray()
> ```

That's because, in Java, writing `new T[]` (where `T` is a generic type) is not allowed, since it would require runtime access to the type `T` and we can't have that due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

So they provide an overload to get around that. The [overload that you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) looks like this.

> ```
> <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
> ```

*You* have to allocate the array and *you* have to make the `new` call, since you know what type of array you want. If you give Java an array of the appropriate type, it can use *that* array. If there's not enough elements in that array, it can use reflection to generate a bigger one of the same type.

So all you're doing is telling Java, at runtime, that the type of array you want is an array containing `int[]` (or a `int[][]`).

Now, as for why we make an array of *zero* elements, that's a bit more complicated (and I don't pretend to fully understand the optimizations in play either), but it's explained in [this blog post](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). There would certainly be nothing *wrong* with giving it a `new int[N][]`, where `N` is the length of your list. But, based on the optimizations currently available to the JVM, the zero array is recommended today.